# Como conectar un WordPress a apache docker

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, docker

Tengo el servidor Apache y MySQL en dos contenedores docker y estoy intentando conectar wordpress que lo tengo en mi pc local a los contenedores, el archivo de wp_config lo tengo apuntando al contenedor MySQL, con el contenedor apache intenté conectarlo con un volumen para enlazar las dos rutas pero nada, si alguien me puede ayudar.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Este es una sección del docker-compose que utilicé una vez para montrar un wordpress. No sé la forma en la que has montado los volumenes, espero te sirva.

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ../../data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql

  wordpress:
      image: wordpress@sha256:9caaf7d238fb6663d3abcccbf9d337a9c8821f2f45a08837ed3ef9f6f73208d1
      volumes:
        - ../../data/wordpress/html:/var/www/html
```